# How to run multiple "mvn test"-commands from batch file?

Tags: maven, batch-file

I need to execute maven tests from another program, in this case HP QC/ALM. I want to execute specific tests, and so I have written a .bat-file that looks like this:

```
cd C:\myPath\
call mvn -Dtest=myPackage.MyTestClass test
call mvn -Dtest=myPackage.MyOtherTest test
```

First of all I am calling the path where the pom.xml file is located. This is needed even if the .bat-file is in the same directory.
second I am calling a specific extension of a `TestCase`-class, with multiple test methods. I am using JUnit 3.
third I am calling another specific `TestCase`-class.

The first TestCase is executed as expected. My problem is that the execution stops after the first TestCase. The `call` keyword is supposed to force the execution to continue, but it has no effect here. Wether the tests are succesful or not makes no difference.

I can't seem to find any other suggestions than the call keyword to solve this problem. Am I using it wrong? Does anyone have any idea why it does not work? Are there other solutions or suggestions I could try?

**UPDATED WITH ADDITIONAL INFO:**

Command line execution stops after the following output:

```
Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 82.964 sec

Results :

Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

This is the 11 tests included in `myPackage.MyTestClass`

Comment: Not that this is the solution to the actual issue but you could use `mvn -f \path\to\project\pom.xml ...` instead of `cd` to the projects`directory.

Comment: I tried it with a `.bat`containing `call mvn -f myproject\pom.xml test` **\n** `call mvn -f myproject\pom.xml test` and it worked like a charm. Where does the execution stop exactly? Within your first project or between the `call`s? Can you supply the output of the cmd line?

Comment: maybe you just need to run mvn in batch mode (with -B)

Comment: the end of the command line is: Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 82.964 sec

Results :

Tests run: 11, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: I break convention with the coding style, by the way. I implement a separate project to run my tests on a deployed war-file (behaviour tests in-browser), and so my maven project has no src/main elements at all. It only has src/test-classes. The tests execute as expected, but the command line never becomes available for input again. It seems like the process doesn't really stop. The project is specified as a jar-package type. I tried pom, but then it didn't execute any tests at all. On the other hand, it completed all lines of the batch file, and returned controll of the command line input.

Answer (score 0):

the way i use for run specific suite of test cases is:

1. In the pom.xml, indicate the suites

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">  
> ....
> <build>
>         <plugins>
>             <plugin>
>                 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>                 <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
>                 <version>2.18.1</version>
>                 <configuration>
>                     <parallel>methods</parallel>
>                     <threadCount>10</threadCount>
>                     <suiteXmlFiles>
>                         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/login/suite001</suiteXmlFile>
>                         <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/other/suite002</suiteXmlFile>
>                     </suiteXmlFiles>
>                 </configuration>
>             </plugin>
>         </plugins>
>     </build>
> </project>
> ```

2. in the suite specifi the test cases do you want included. You can include an entire packege if yoou want.

> ```
> <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
> <suite name="suite100LoginCliente" verbose="1" >
>     <test name="testName001"   >
>         <packages>
>             <package name="login" />
>         </packages>
>     </test>
> </suite>
> ```

3. run a batch file to run the test

> ```
> @echo off
> cls
> echo Welcome to .
> cd C:\blabla\mavenProyect
> call mvn test
> echo Press anything to exit :D
> Pause>Nul
> ```

That's all i know until now. If you found a better for way do this, please let know ;)